# Strings shortened when using UNION in Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, union, teradata-sql-assistant

When I perform a UNION between 2 tables, the strings are automatically shortened. I get "**30 Days Active Su**" and "**120 Days Active S**". When I run the query individually, without any UNION, I get the full form "30 Days Active Subs" and "120 Days Active Subs", which I require. Why is this so and how to go about correcting it?

Following is the code:

```
SELECT
'30 Days Active Subs' AS PROPERTY
,(DISTINCT SUBS.SUBSCRIBER_COUNT) AS SUBS_COUNT
FROM PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_DLY_SNAP AS SUBS
WHERE SUBS.DAYS=30
GROUP BY 1

UNION

SELECT 
'120 Days Active Subs' AS PROPERTY
,(DISTINCT SUBS.SUBSCRIBER_COUNT) AS SUBS_COUNT
FROM PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_DLY_SNAP AS SUBS
WHERE SUBS.DAYS=120
```

Comment: Note that it is useless to provide a different alias on the second SELECT. The column will called "30_DAYS_SUBS" anyway, which will be quite misleading for records coming from the second SELECT, so you'd better choose a more general name, such as "SUBS_COUNT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast this column.

```
SELECT
CAST('30 Days Active Subs' AS varchar(255)) AS PROPERTY
,(DISTINCT SUBS.SUBSCRIBER_COUNT) AS "30_DAYS_SUBS"
FROM PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_DLY_SNAP AS SUBS
WHERE SUBS.DAYS=30
GROUP BY 1

UNION

SELECT 
'120 Days Active Subs' AS PROPERTY
,(DISTINCT SUBS.SUBSCRIBER_COUNT) AS "120_DAYS_SUBS"
FROM PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_DLY_SNAP AS SUBS
WHERE SUBS.DAYS=120
```

or you can use fixed length

```
 CAST('30 Days Active Subs' AS CHARACTER(20))
```

Comment: "120 Days Active S",
"30 Days Active Su".
Stil gave this after casting and applying varchar(255)

Comment: use fix length  `CAST('30 Days Active Subs' AS CHARACTER(20))`